# How to store Pending Edits to Records for an Approval Flow in a Model-Driven Power App?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-modeldriven

I am fairly new to Power Apps. I am modifying an existing Model-Driven App to add an Approval feature for edits to a record and was hoping to get your feedback on the best implementation approach. When a user Edits values to a form, which contains subgrids to many other related tables that are editable, we want to trigger an Approvals notification for an approver to review the edits across all these related tables, to either Approve or Reject, or Approve with Changes, i.e. the Approver can make changes to the User edits and then hit Approve. Would the proposed solution work? Or would you have a better suggestion for a solution to this? Thank you so much in advance.

**Current Solution Structure**

1. There are multiple related tables
2. A main form that has sub grids of the related tables
3. A model-driven app that auto saves

**Proposed Solution**

1. Create a 'duplicate' "Approvals" table for all existing tables with same structure as the original tables to hold the edits, for example

   1. If I have a table "TableA" create a duplicate table called "TableAApprovals" with an additional "ApprovalStatus" choice column (Approved or Rejected or Approve with Changes)
2. When the form is modified and Save button is clicked, trigger an Approvals flow

   1. Disable Auto-Save on the Main Form using this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/manage-auto-save
   2. On save button click

      1. Save the changes to "TableXApprovals" tables with same structure as the original tables.
      2. Trigger an Approval flow that will take the values from the TableXApprovals tables and include in Approvals notifications e.g. in Teams Approvals App
      3. Approval notification can provide a deep link into a TableXApprovals form for Approver Editing
3. Approver can make any adjustments to the TableXApprovals form and then Approve, Approve with Changes or can Reject

   1. If Approved, then copy the changes from the "Pending Edits" table into the main/original table and Update Approval Status in "Pending Edits" table
   2. If Rejected, update Approval Status in "Pending Edits" table

**Questions**

1. Regarding 1 is this a poor approach to begin with to create duplicate table (appending Approvals suffix) to store the Edits to be approved?
2. Regarding 2.2.1 can OnSave programmatically save all the edits to each of the Sub Grids TableXApprovals tables?

Thank you in advance for you help and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still require assistance here.

I added an IsApproved column to my Dataverse table and update this column on approval. Then, I would use filters to display the desired results.